# I can logon only to SQL>

Tags: oracle11g, sqlplus

All the time when I'm trying login myself to sqlplus I log on to `SQL>` but I don`t know what I have to do to got Main user account for example [oracle@host01~] ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SQL>` prompt is the default in SQLPlus.  You can change it on the commnadline, once logged in, to a custom string.  try:

```
set sqlprompt "_USER'@'_CONNECT_IDENTIFIER > "
```

to show your user and the DB you are connected to.

from [this page](http://psoug.org/reference/sqlplus.html), we can see the following default keywords that you can use:

- **_CONNECT_IDENTIFIER**  Connection identifier used to make connection, where available.
- **_DATE**                Current date, or a user defined fixed string.
- **_EDITOR**  Specifies the editor used by the EDIT command.
- **_O_RELEASE**   Full release number of the installed Oracle Database.
- **_O_VERSION**   Current version of the installed Oracle Database.
- **_PRIVILEGE**   Privilege level of the current connection.
- **_SQLPLUS_RELEASE** Full release number of installed SQL*Plus component.
- **_USER**    User name used to make connection.

Comment: do you know why I have got problem now system don`t understand code SP2-0734 -> SYS@orcl>lsnrctl stop listener